# How to integrate Rally Rest Api with Java?

Tags: java, web-services, rally

Currently i'm integrating **Rally Rest Service** into my Java Project. But when i try to connect Rally, getting below error

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://rally1.rallydev.com refused.

Could you please any one help me on this issue.

Comment: post your code snippet and the rest service call that you are making .

Comment: RallyRestApi restAPI = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"), "APIKEY");
   QueryRequest req = new QueryRequest("User");
   String[] fetchUserValues = new String[20];
   fetchUserValues[0] = "Name"; 
   fetchUserValues[1] = "Owner";
   fetchUserValues[2] = "Projects";
   req.setFetch(new Fetch(fetchUserValues));
   QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restAPI.query(req);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks ok.  Is it possible that you are behind a proxy?

```
restAPI.setProxy(new URI("http://my.proxy.com:8000"));
```

Comment: that's don't know @kyle Morse.

Comment: Yeah.We running under proxy only @Kyle Morse

Comment: its working fine now when i'm adding proxy. thank you @Kyle Morse